# NHibernate - No Class Mappings

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

Why don't I have any class mappings after calling Configuration.Configure()?

Here is my class mapping file Category.hbm.xml for BudgetModel.Category:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="BudgetModel" namespace="BudgetModel">
  <class name="Category" table="Categories">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="string" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### EDIT

NH version is 2.1.1.GA

Category.hbm.xml is an embedded resource & I have rebuilt.

Comment: what does your nhibernate.config (or hibernate.cfg.xml) file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell NHibernate where your mapping files are. You normally do this either programmatically or in the configuration file.

```
config.AddAssembly(typeof(Category).Assembly);
```

or

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <!--Configuration Properties-->
    <mapping assembly="BudgetModel" />    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also, your hibernate mapping file must be set with a build action of embedded resource.